# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to load csv data into a database that I've already built, and am getting the above noted error. The CSV file only has 29 rows, everything is spelled correctly, I just don't know if I'm missing out on some small piece of syntax? Can anyone recommend how to resolve this or where I may be going wrong?

My function is detailed below:

```py
def load_csv_to_db():
    db_file_name = 'records.db'
    csv_file_name = '13100262.csv'

    SQL = """
    insert into records_table (ref_date,geo,dguid,sex,age_group,student_response,uom,uom_id,scalar_factor,scalar_id,
    vector,coordinate,value,status,symbol,terminated,decimals) values (:ref_date,:geo,:dguid,:sex,:age_group,
    :student_response,:uom,:uom_id,:scalar_factor,:scalar_id,:vector,:coordinate,:value,:status,:symbol,:terminated,
    :decimals)"""

    with open(csv_file_name, 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        with sq.connect(db_file_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.executemany(SQL, csv_reader)
```

Comment: I think it's how I've cut and pasted into here. It does not give me an indentation error. I'll try to adjust.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63592114/1497139 for getting better debug info

Answer (score 0):

The first row of the spreadsheet does not contain a column whose contents are (the literal) "ref_date".

Since program is using `DictReader`, assume the first line of spreadsheet is column titles, which must *exactly* match the placeholder names used in the SQL (though not necessarily the order).